# Running minitest handler tests inside another ruby script

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'd like to run my minitest handler tests inside another ruby script (a bootstrapper script of sorts).  I'd like to return the results of my tests to a variable that I can then parse to make sure everything passed before moving on. Is this possible? If so, what does the syntax for something like this look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out how to do this using the rake::test library. This code will execute a minitest test, then slurp in the xml from the report and determine if everything passed or not.

```
    require 'rake'
    require 'rake/testtask'
    require 'ci/reporter/rake/minitest'
    require 'xmlsimple'

    Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
      t.verbose = true
      t.test_files = FileList['system_tests/vm_tests.rb']
    end
    task :test => :"ci:setup:minitest"
    Rake::Task[:test].execute
    results = XmlSimple.xml_in('test/reports/TEST-VMtests.xml')
    if results["failures"] > 0 or results["errors"] > 0
      raise "The VM Tests have resulted in failures or errors"
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shell out to run the test and capture the output.

```
puts "Running foo test:"
output = `ruby -Ilib:test test/test_foo.rb`
puts output
puts "Completed foo test."
```

Comment: Yes, that definitely works.  Is there a way to invoke this without making a system call? It seems kind of redundant to make a system call to ruby from with inside a ruby script